# Asp.Net Web Api Multipost Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

So, i'm trying to pass multiple parameters from fiddler to my web api, using `FormDataCollection.ReadAsNameValueCollection()`. 
Problem is everytime is send my data, `formData` comes back as null. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I've tried decorating `formData` with a `[FromBody]` attribute. Also registered `JsonMediaTypeFormatter()` in the global.asax class.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Please see code below:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage PostAccount([FromBody]FormDataCollection formData)
{
    if (formData != null)
    {
        var nValueCol = formData.ReadAsNameValueCollection();

        var account = new Account()
        {
            Email = nValueCol["email"],
            Password = nValueCol["password"],
            AgreedToTerms = Convert.ToBoolean(nValueCol["agreesToTerms"]),
            //LocationAccountCreated = DbGeography.FromText(nValueCol["userLocation"])
        };

        var userProfile = new UserProfile()
        {
            FirstName = nValueCol["firstName"],
            LastName = nValueCol["lastName"],
            DateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(nValueCol["dateOfBirth"])
        };

        var newAcc = _accountService.CreateAccount(account.Email, userProfile.FirstName, userProfile.LastName,
                                                    userProfile.DateOfBirth, account.Email, account.AgreedToTerms,
                                                    account.LocationAccountCreated);
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);

        return response;
    }
    else
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable);
}
```

Sample request:

[image: Fiddler Post Request]

Comment: Which Content-Type are you sending in the request? Could you show us the request body?

Comment: Hi Federico, i have uploaded the fiddler request screenshot. I did however use application/json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FormDataCollection` is normally associated with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` media type.

Your screen shot shows you are trying to send json data. If you don't have a concrete data type for your data and you want to send it as Json you can use an `IDictionary<string,string>` which will be mapped by the model binder successfully.

You action will look something like...

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage PostAccount([FromBody]IDictionary<string, string> formData) {
    if (formData != null) {
        var nValueCol = formData;
        //...other code removed for brevity, but can basically stay the same
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        return response;
    } else
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable);
}
```

Based on your code and the information from your fiddler screen shot, a TestController was created, a request was tested with fiddler like...

```
POST http://localhost:35979/api/account/create HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:35979
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 76

{"email":"myemail@email.com",
"firstname":"myFName",
"lastName":"myLName"}
```

...and the `formData` was populate with the 3 fields and their data.